# Get foreach data result as a variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have following model function:

```
function getdata_naoh($datetest2) {
    $result = $this->db1->query("select round(avg(cast(t_dtl.hasil_m as decimal(6,4))),4) as hasil_m from t_hdr JOIN  t_dtl ON t_hdr.headerid = t_dtl.headerid where id_solvent ='NaOH' AND status='ok' AND concentrate='0.0100' AND date_start <='$datetest2' AND date_finish >='$datetest2'");
    if($result->num_rows()>0) {
        return $result->result_array();
    }else {
        return array();
    }
}
```

And a controller function:

```
function get_NaOH() {
    $date_analysis = trim($this->input->post('date_analysis'));
    $datetest = trim($this->input->post('date_analysis'));
    $datetest2 = substr($datetest,6,4).'-'.substr($datetest,3,2).'-'.substr($datetest,0,2);

    $dtnaoh = $this->M_tambahan->getdata_naoh($datetest2);

    $data1 = 0;    
    foreach($dtnaoh as $row) {
        $data1 = $row['hasil_m'];
    }

    $data = $data1;
    echo $data;
}
```

The query result would be like:

```
| hasil_m     |
| ----------- |
| 0.0100      |
```

I want to get `hasil_m` column, according to the controller function, i set variable `data1 = 0`

then in *foreach* statement change the value as a result from `hasil_m` but when i echo variable `$data` i still getting `data1` value = **0**, did i miss something ?

Any help would be appreciated greatly, thank you.

Comment: `print_r($dtnaoh)` and post the data

Comment: @Abdulla here is the result `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [hasil_m] => 
        )

)
0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop, you're overwriting the variable with the new value. If you want to sum all of the `hasil_m` data into `$data1` then simply modify your `foreach` loop as the following:

```
foreach($dtnaoh as $row) {
    $data1 += $row['hasil_m'];
}
```

---

For debugging purposes, could you update your question to show exactly what the query returns?

#### Edit

Seems you've got `float`'s! You'll need to harness [`floatval()`](http://php.net/floatval) in your loop to pass the values through:

```
foreach($dtnaoh as $row) {
    $data1 += floatval($row['hasil_m']);
}
```

<sup>*This happens because your initial variable (`$data1`) is treated as a string. Meaning it doesn't and won't show the float values, treating it as a whole number.*</sup>

Comment: i've edited the question and added the query returns. `$data1 += $row['hasil_m']` still doesn't work, and `$data1` still showing *0* as a result

Comment: not working, `$data1` keep showing **0** but if i removed the initial variable `$data1 = 0` then i get `Undefined variable: data1`

Comment: @metaphor What PHP version are you using? As it works [**here**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#AwAs2tiZ6).

Comment: i'm using PHP 5.4.16

Comment: Hi @darren your code works fine, i've just used a wrong database (development database) it was my bad, thats why the result keep showing **0** because dev database doesn't contain any records. Thanks for your help.